# Move selected cells up/down on Jupyter on Pycharm (Python 2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7, pycharm, anaconda, jupyter

I am using *Jupyter* on *Pycharm* (first picture) and I can't find the commands to move selected cells up/down that exist in Jupyter Anaconda (2nd picture)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In my computer I can do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>up</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>down</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

PyCharm 2020 (and up) has the arrow buttons in the toolbar.

[image: Toolbar]

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> seems to be the only way to do that